# Color every line when hovering over multiline links

Tags: xetex, hyperref, color, hyperlink

When using hyperref, I sometimes get long links split over several lines. The links work as expected no matter what line I choose to click, but the link background color changes for the current line only. Is it possible to have all of the line's background change color instead?

I don't know if it is relevant, but I'm using XeLatex.

Comment: no, there are independant links.

Comment: Many viewers don't show the background color at all. On my system only PDF.js (the default viewer in Firefox) shows link backgrounds, the Chrome default viewer (PDFium) doesn't show it and also none of my desktop viewers show it (I tried six different ones). So if you want a fully colored link for other people reading your document then there is a high probability that they will not see it anyway because of using a different viewer than you - and if you want it for yourself then you are out of luck I guess...

Comment: (unless you find a viewer that is smart enough to combine adjacent links with the same target into one and highlight them together, but I don't know if such a viewer exists)

Comment: I do indeed use Firefox. When I saw that I could not fix the problem, I tried to look for a way to turn off the background color completely. So that it is only PDF.js that shows them is relatively good news. Thank you for the information.